# Can the Differential Wizard in Trimble Path Finder Office v5.80 use Secure FTP Servers?

Tags: dgps

I have an ALlloy Base Station that writes  correction files to a SFTP server.  I can not get the Differential Correction Wizard to use the network address to retrieve  the appropriate correction files.  Or any file as it appears to me that that PFO does not work with SFTP servers.

Has anyone else had this problem?

Answer (score 0):

The Help file for Pathfinder Office 5.90 says the address for Base File data can be "**an Internet address using the ftp:// or http:// protocol**".  This suggests that FTTPS and HTTPS cannot be used (unless the Differential Correction Utility has been updated without updating the Help file.)  (***Edit 22Aug2022:***) I emailed a colleague who does support work on the older Trimble applications, he confirmed that PFO does not support Secure FTP.  Two possible work-arounds I can think of are as follows:

- Set up your base station so it saves to an FTP Server not to a Secure
  server.  This may not be supported - newer firmware often only
  supports secure servers.
- Manually download the files you need from the FTP server to a local
  drive (as RINEX v2.11, not a later version) then point the PFO Differential Correction wizard to the files on the local drive.